# Two protocols with associated types: How to link their implementations in a type-safe way?

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, associated-types

### Goal

When creating a networking layer for my apps, I typically use a generic method to fetch data from the server, e.g.

```
func fetch<R: Resource>(_ resource: R, completion: ((Result<R.Model, Error>) -> Void))
```

I find this to be very elegant as I only need to implement my fetch method once, but still get type-safety with this protocol:

```
protocol Resource {
    associatedType Model
    var endPointPath: String { get }
}
```

This way, I can easily add new Resources (endpoints) anytime without modifying existing code and the resource that includes the API endpoint is always directly hooked up with the result's `Model` type via the associated type – I always know what I get when fetching a given `Resource`.

### Example

I could simply fetch this resource:

```
struct ArticlesResource: Resource {
    typealias Model = [Article]
    let endPointPath = "/articles" 
}
```

with this call and get a type-safe model back:

```
myAPI.fetch(ArticleResource()) { result in
    switch result {
        case let .success(model):
            // model is of type [Article]
        case .failure:
            // Request failed...
    }
}
```

This approach always served me well – until now.

### The Problem

Now I'm dealing with a given networking framework that uses (surprise!) the same approach as I do: It also uses a protocol for defining a request and that protocol also has an associated type for the result of the network call.

I need to wrap this concrete networking framework so that it's not exposed outside of my own networking layer (as it is an implementation detail that the consumer of my networking layer should not be concerned with).

So let's assume, this 3rd party framework has the same API as my own networking layer (just with different model and resource types):
Both have a `fetch` method that is generic in the (domain-specific) resource type that is associated with the respective model type (via an associated type, see diagram).

#### How do I now implement my fetch method?

```
struct MyAPI {

    private let networkingClient: ThirdPartyNetworkingClient

    func fetch<R: Resource>(_ resource: R, completion: ((Result<R.Model, Error>) -> Void)) {
        // 1. Map my own Resource to ThirdPartyResource
        let networkResource = ? 
        // 2. Fetch ThirdPartyResource
        networkingClient.fetch(networkResource) { result in
            // 3. Map ThirdPartyModel to my own Model
            let model = R.Model(...) 
            // 4. Return my own Model to the app via completion handler
            completion(.success(model))
        }
    }

}
```

(In the example above I assume the happy path for brevity and ignored any errors.)

In step 1, I have a problem: I am inside a generic function scope, so I would need a method that maps my own Resource type `R` to the `ThirdPartyResourceType` in a generic way.

```
func mapToThirdPartyResource<R: Resource>(_ myResource: R) -> ThirdPartyResource {
    // ... map ...
}
```

However, `ThirdPartyResourceType` has an associated type requirement, so any function with such a signature would not compile. Y'all know this infamous Swift compiler error:

> ```
> Protocol 'ThirdPartyResourceType' can only be used as a generic constraint 
> because it has Self or associated type requirements
> ```

Without specifying the protocol's associated type, the type information is not complete and so the compiler can't work with it (only as a generic constraint). So there can be no generic function that maps any given Resource to its respective
`ThirdPartyResourceType`.

Similarly, in step 3, I cannot map back from the 3rd party library's model type to my own Model type for the same reason.

### Question

While it seems to me like this is a language limitation of Swift that simply prevents me from doing this, I'm not entirely certain I see all alternatives clearly enough. Is there a way to achieve the described networking layer abstraction without losing type safety?

Logically, the entire chain is strongly linked:

```
Resource → ThirdPartyResource
                  ↓
Model    ← ThirdPartyModel
```

I am looking for a way to wire it exactly like this in Swift, to connect all these types in a generic way – without exposing the `ThirdPartyResorce` and `-Model` to the outside world (the consumer app). So is there a way to ship around this limitation?

[image: Architecture Sketch]

---

## [Edit] Example for Protocol Declarations & Mapping

To make things a little more concrete, here are two sample protocols:

#### Used by my own Networking Layer (exposed to client app)

```
protocol Resource {
    associatedtype Model
}
```

#### Used by my 3rd Party Library (hidden from the client app)

```
protocol ThirdPartyResource {
    associatedtype Model
    var query: String { get }
}
```

#### Fetch Methods

The 3rd party networking library might have a networking client that exposes the following generic `fetch` function:

```
struct ThirdPartyNetworkingClient {
    func fetch<R: ThirdPartyResource>(_ resouce: R, completion: (Result<R.Model, Error>) -> ()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

That function is an implementation detail and shall not be exposed to the client app. Instead, my networking layer exposes its own generic `fetch` function that operates on my `Resource` protocol rather than the `ThirdPartyResource`:

```
func fetch<R: Resource>(_ resource: R, completion: (Result<R.Model, Error>) -> ()) {
    let thirdPartyResource = thirdPartyResource(for: resource) // 1️⃣ Mapping
    thridPartyNetworkingClient.fetch(thirdPartyResource) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let thirdPartyModel):
            let model = // 2️⃣ map ThirdPartyResource.Model to our Resource.Model and return to client
            completion(.success(model))
            break
        case .failure:
            // handle error
            break
        }
    }
}
```

The generic mapping functions I'm looking for (that this question is all about) are marked with 1️⃣ and 2️⃣ respectively. I need a point to convert a `Resource` to the respective `ThirdPartyResource` in order to perform the request with the 3rd party networking client, and when it returns a result, I need a way to map the `ThirdPartyResource.Model` back to my own layer's model (`Resource.Model`).

Hope this makes things clearer.

Comment: Isn't `3rdPartyModel` the same as `Model`? It would be strange for the 3rd party framework to model the response type in other ways than your `Resource` does. If it does, then you're a little bit out of luck, as you'll have to write overloads for every model you want to support.

Comment: I cannot control which model type a given 3rd party framework uses, but the whole point of writing my network layer is to make the 3rd party stuff replaceable under the hood. If I use the same model type for my own network layer, it bleeds through to the app and I make myself dependent on the concrete framework I use.

I also see the 3rd party framework's model as some kind of "raw data" (despite being strongly typed) while my own model shall be tailored to what the app really uses, so my own model is a polished (and possibly restructured) version of the framework's model.

Comment: Can you update the question with a use case? The question so far, even if very detailed, would benefit from a concrete example, so we can better understand the problem.

Comment: I think that would kind of explode the question which is already super long as I would need to write down the Resource protocols for both my own networking layer and the 3rd party library, plus a Model type for both which in turn would require several nested structs to make the use case clear. Might post that in a separate question and link it here, but I think it would just blow up this question. (Tried to come up with a minimal example, but it's already 65 lines, so not really suitable to be appended here.)

Comment: At least can you add the actual protocol declarations, and the function declarations that make use of those protocols?

Comment: Sure. Added the protocols and als the fetch functions where the problem occurs that my question is revolving around.

Comment: OK, so the same `Model` is propagated downstream, right?

Comment: No, it's a different `Model`. `ThirdPartyResource.Model` and `Resource.Model` are two different arbitrary types. That's the idea: The model type the my networking library returns is automatically generated and deeply nested. So I want to convert it to a flattened model that is 1. easier to use in the app and 2. independent of the concrete network library I use.

Comment: I think you're out of luck if you need to hide both the request and the model. For the request there are techniques to hide it, however I don't think it's possible to hide both of them and still keep type safety.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I miss something, but I think the problem from step 1 maybe could be solved like this:

```swift
struct AnyThirdPartyResource<M>: ThirdPartyResource {
  typealias Model = M
  var query: String
  
  init(_ query: String) {
    self.query = query
  }
}

func transform<R: Resource>(_ resource: R) -> AnyThirdPartyResource<R.Model> {
  return AnyThirdPartyResource<R.Model>(resource.query)
}
```

The `AnyThirdPartyResource` type does not have to be exposed to the client and is just used in the fetch function.

In regards to problem 2, I think if the two Model types are not the same, you'd have to specify a transform function from ThirdPartyResource.Model -> Resource.Model. Maybe this could be an internal function on the respective Resource of your framework?